# What is the source of origin of the creation of the Warehouse building in Warehouse 13?

Tags: warehouse-13

Where does the concept of the warehouse creation come from? Alexander started it, but where did the origin of its organic existence form? Warehouse 1? Warehouse 2 had the beginnings of sentience. Was it given life then, or in the beginning? And from what?